# Insert images in listview of Adapter class according to the condition of Main Activity class

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

My title might seems unclear to you.

Due to new in Java and lack of logic I want to ask you simple thing.

I have a  Activity class, where there is list of trainings with two text views and one image view. OnClick to the listView I want to go to the next activity in some conditions. That condition you can see below in code.

Activity class;

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    currentTraining = (Training) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);

    SharedMemory.getInstance().setCurrentTraining(currentTraining);

    startTraining();

}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private void startTraining() throws ParseException {

    // current date & time
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    // parse date & time from database
    String trainingStartDate = SharedMemory.getInstance()
            .getCurrentTraining().getDate();

    String trainingStartTime = SharedMemory.getInstance()
            .getCurrentTraining().getStartTime();

    String strDateTime = trainingStartDate + " " + trainingStartTime;

    Calendar training = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        training.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")
                .parse(strDateTime));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // find difference in milliseconds
    long difference = training.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();

    if (difference < 15 * 60 * 1000) { // less than 15 minutes

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                TraineeListActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        finish();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "The training starts on" + " " + trainingStartDate + " at "
                        + trainingStartTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

To get these lists of training I am using BaseAdapter that extends TrainingAdapter.

My TrainingAdapter class;

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.trainingadapter, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.training_title);
        holder.trainingDetails = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.training_dtls);
        holder.lockImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lockImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtName.setText(trainingsList.get(position).getTitle());

    holder.trainingDetails.setText("In "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getLocation() + " on "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getDate() + " at "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getStartTime() + " - "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getEndTime() + " by "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getTrainer());

    **HERE-->** holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unlock);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView trainingDetails;
    TextView txtName;
    ImageView lockImage;

}
```

In imageView (lockImage) I want to set one image to the listView that the training has time to start and another image when the training is not ready to start. The training start condition can bee seen in activity class. Thanks for your help in advance..

Comment: so what is your problem. check condition and replace image??

Comment: Do you mean that In activity class inside if else condition I put two different images??

Comment: in BaseAdapter getview method put condition

Comment: I do not know how can I implement that. If u could some small code hint please..

Comment: I mean what condition??

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() method solved your problem

Comment: @mcd In your answer, it shows images only ontouch. I do not understand why??

Comment: You want to set different image depending upon the condition in list view .,.right??

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Exactly!!

Comment: So M telling this only to you naa

Comment: @SweetWisherツ ????????? what are to telling :D I am sorry. I don't get u now.

Comment: I already tol u to **set the required image in DataModel and then pass this DataModel to adapter**. I can't explain you more..

Comment: calm down. I am sorry I am a bit slow (Tube light) :D Thanks for the help. I will give it a try. Actually I tried this way u said also but did not help. I will gain give it a try  :)

Comment: check my answer..it'z just an idea..You have to implement actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I managed to answer this way;
In model class;

```
public boolean isLocked() {

boolean returnCode = true;
// current date & time
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

// parse date & time from database
String trainingStartDate = this.getDate();

String trainingStartTime = this.getStartTime();

String strDateTime = trainingStartDate + " " + trainingStartTime;

Calendar training = Calendar.getInstance();

try {
    training.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")
            .parse(strDateTime));

    long difference = training.getTimeInMillis()
            - now.getTimeInMillis();

    if (difference < 15 * 60 * 1000) { // less than 15 minutes


        returnCode = false;
    }

} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //returnCode = false;
}

return returnCode;
```

In activity class;

```
private void startTraining() {

// parse date & time from database
String trainingStartDate = SharedMemory.getInstance()
    .getCurrentTraining().getDate();

String trainingStartTime = SharedMemory.getInstance()
        .getCurrentTraining().getStartTime();

if ((currentTraining).isLocked()){
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "The training starts on" + " " + trainingStartDate
                    + " at " + trainingStartTime,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            TraineeListActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

    finish();

} }
```

In adapter class;

```
// If training is locked, then display the lock picture
if (trainingsList.get(position).isLocked()) {

    holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lock);

    // else display the unlock picture
} else {

    holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unlock);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity, you have to check for all data in the list.

Suppose your data is in dataArrayList, iterate through dataArrayList and set image accordingly :

```
for(int i=0 ; i< data_size;i++)
{
        if(ur condition)
        {
            //set image 1

           obj.setImage(image1);
        }
        else
        {
            // set image 2
            obj.setImage(image2);
        }
    dataArrayList.add(obj);
}
```

After all data image is set ,pass this data to adapter :

```
TrainingAdapter adapter = new TrainingAdapter(context, dataArrayList) // whtever is ypur argumnets
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Sorry this does not help in my condition. Mine other data are in database. And the image has to change automatically when the condition changes in the list. The condition is startTraining().

Comment: U can invalidate the list

Answer (score 0):

> this will work only for one item in listview you have to pass selected
>   item
>
> ```
>  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
>
>     currentTraining = (Training) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
>
>     SharedMemory.getInstance().setCurrentTraining(currentTraining);
>
>    startTraining()
>
> }
>
> @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
> private void startTraining() throws ParseException {
>
>     // current date & time
>     Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
>
>     // parse date & time from database
>     String trainingStartDate = SharedMemory.getInstance()
>             .getCurrentTraining().getDate();
>
>     String trainingStartTime = SharedMemory.getInstance()
>             .getCurrentTraining().getStartTime();
>
>     String strDateTime = trainingStartDate + " " + trainingStartTime;
>
>     Calendar training = Calendar.getInstance();
>
>     try {
>         training.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")
>                 .parse(strDateTime));
>     } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>     // find difference in milliseconds
>     long difference = training.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();
>
>     if (difference < 15 * 60 * 1000) { // less than 15 minutes
>         /**
>           training start
>         **/       adapter.ViewHolder.status=0;        adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
>         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
>                 TraineeListActivity.class);
>         MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
>
>         finish();
>
>     } else {
>         Toast.makeText(
>                 getApplicationContext(),
>                 "The training starts on" + " " + trainingStartDate + " at "
>                         + trainingStartTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      adapter.ViewHolder.status=1;
>   adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
>       /**
>           training remain
>         **/
>     }
>
> }
>
>
>
>    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>       int tmp_status;  
>         ViewHolder holder;
>         if (convertView == null) {
>             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.trainingadapter, null);
>
>             holder = new ViewHolder();
>             holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
>                     .findViewById(R.id.training_title);
>             holder.trainingDetails = (TextView) convertView
>                     .findViewById(R.id.training_dtls);
>             holder.lockImage = (ImageView) convertView
>                     .findViewById(R.id.lockImage);
>
>             convertView.setTag(holder);
>
>         } else {
>             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
>              tmp_status=holder.status;
>         }
>         holder.txtName.setText(trainingsList.get(position).getTitle());
>
>         holder.trainingDetails.setText("In "
>                 + trainingsList.get(position).getLocation() + " on "
>                 + trainingsList.get(position).getDate() + " at "
>                 + trainingsList.get(position).getStartTime() + " - "
>                 + trainingsList.get(position).getEndTime() + " by "
>                 + trainingsList.get(position).getTrainer());
> if( tmp_status==0)
>         **HERE-->** holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unlock);
>     else
>              something
>         return convertView;
>     }
>
>     static class ViewHolder {
>
>         TextView trainingDetails;
>         TextView txtName;
>         ImageView lockImage;
>         int status;
>     }
> ```

Comment: but onClick to the listView how will the startTraining() event occurs?

Comment: And how could the int -1 can be inside else{}block.

Comment: And I cannot call startTraining() method in TrainingAdapter class. It ask to be the method static which the intent does not work in that time.

Comment: sorry i am not understand what you are trying to do. 
1) there is only one item in listview?????

Comment: you have to notifydatasetchanged method and update your listview when user click. so i think you have to put setnotifydatasetchanged within startTraining method

Comment: yeah in a list view there is two text views and one image view. You can consider that as a single training or one item.

Comment: You did not get me man. I do not want to change anything when user clicks. I want to implement two images in image view of each item in two different situation. One situation is when the training time is ready to start and another is when the training time is not ready.

Comment: int tmp_status;  It asks to initialize value.

Comment: Your code is working fine only on the touch of list view. I want to have different images in the list before ontouch.

Comment: pass the desired image in adapter only

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I can do it normally but I want to pass different images according to the condition of the training. Like, when the training is not ready to start use one image and when training is ready to start different image.

Comment: yeah I know then put this condition n set data according in adapter only na

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Sorry, I cannot come to chatroom. I am at work. It is blocked.

Comment: When u fill the arraylist for the adapter.U have to check for the condition

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I believe the answer provided here should work. And I tried to check the condition that way using flags. But it is working only after onTouch to the listview. If u could edit the answer above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47631/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-bshah)

Comment: I cannot access the chat room from here.

Comment: will check when will get moment.. m bit busy now