# Change the image in ListView automatically according to the conditions

Tags: android, listview, conditional-statements, baseadapter

It can be the copy of the same question what I asked some couple of days ago:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776669/insert-images-in-listview-of-adapter-class-according-to-the-condition-of-main-ac). I received one answer there that almost met my requirement but not totally. I am again posting this because I want to have attention of you guys. Sorry for that.
In Activity class.

```
    try {
        training.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")
                .parse(strDateTime));

        long difference = training.getTimeInMillis()
                - now.getTimeInMillis();

        if (difference < 15 * 60 * 1000) { // less than 15 minutes

            TrainingAdapter.ViewHolder.status = 1;
            trainingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    TraineeListActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

            finish();

        } else {

            TrainingAdapter.ViewHolder.status = 1;
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "The training starts on" + " " + trainingStartDate
                            + " at " + trainingStartTime,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In Adapter class;

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    int tmp_status = 0;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.trainingadapter, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.training_title);
        holder.trainingDetails = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.training_dtls);
        holder.lockImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lockImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        tmp_status = ViewHolder.status;
    }
    holder.txtName.setText(trainingsList.get(position).getTitle());

    holder.trainingDetails.setText("In "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getLocation() + " on "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getDate() + " at "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getStartTime() + " - "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getEndTime() + " by "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getTrainer());

    if (tmp_status == 0) {
        System.out.println(tmp_status);
        holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unlock);

    } else if (tmp_status == 1) {
        System.out.println(tmp_status);
        holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lock);
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView trainingDetails;
    TextView txtName;
    ImageView lockImage;
    public static int status;

}
```

Here, the image is changing according to the value of **int tmp_status = 0;** . If I initialize value to 1, only it gives another image but to all list views. In Activity class you can see the conditions of each list is different i.e. intent to another activity. Could you figure out where is the problem.

Comment: FYI, status is static variable that means it will be only one instance for your class.
So your TrainingAdapter.ViewHolder.status = 1; is 1 for all rows of listview

Comment: Is it not possible to set different images in different listViews??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to do it in this way;

Im model class;

```
public boolean isLocked() {

    boolean returnCode = true;
    // current date & time
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    // parse date & time from database
    String trainingStartDate = this.getDate();

    String trainingStartTime = this.getStartTime();

    String strDateTime = trainingStartDate + " " + trainingStartTime;

    Calendar training = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        training.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")
                .parse(strDateTime));

        long difference = training.getTimeInMillis()
                - now.getTimeInMillis();

        if (difference < 15 * 60 * 1000) { // less than 15 minutes


            returnCode = false;
        }

    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //returnCode = false;
    }

    return returnCode;  
}
```

In Activity class;

```
private void startTraining() {

    // parse date & time from database
    String trainingStartDate = SharedMemory.getInstance()
        .getCurrentTraining().getDate();

    String trainingStartTime = SharedMemory.getInstance()
            .getCurrentTraining().getStartTime();

    if ((currentTraining).isLocked()){
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "The training starts on" + " " + trainingStartDate
                        + " at " + trainingStartTime,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                TraineeListActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        finish();

    }
}
```

In Adapter class;

```
// If training is locked, then display the lock picture
    if (trainingsList.get(position).isLocked()) {

        holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lock);

        // else display the unlock picture
    } else {

        holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unlock);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Status variable from ViewHolder.
ViewHolder is only for views.
You have to keep status saperatly for each row.It can be List of Integer or List of Pojo's.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    int tmp_status = 0;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.trainingadapter, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.training_title);
        holder.trainingDetails = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.training_dtls);
        holder.lockImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lockImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    }
    tmp_status = listOfStatuses.get(position);
    holder.txtName.setText(trainingsList.get(position).getTitle());

    holder.trainingDetails.setText("In "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getLocation() + " on "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getDate() + " at "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getStartTime() + " - "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getEndTime() + " by "
            + trainingsList.get(position).getTrainer());

    if (tmp_status == 0) {
        System.out.println(tmp_status);
        holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unlock);

    } else if (tmp_status == 1) {
        System.out.println(tmp_status);
        holder.lockImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lock);
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView trainingDetails;
    TextView txtName;
    ImageView lockImage;

}
```

Comment: If I remove that, how can I set condition in the activity class?? like in there, In one condition the status is 0 and in another condition the status is 1.

Comment: Like I said you have to store status in ArrayList of Integer for each Position of list and check it in geview

Comment: Check "listOfStatuses" is the list you have to create and pass it to Adapter.

Comment: Do you mean the listOfStatuses will be the array list of my images

Comment: No it will be arraylist of status int's

Comment: Why would I need that? Or how can I implement that?

Comment: You have to do this because you need status of image for each row in listview.This status can be different for every row of listview.

instead of TrainingAdapter.ViewHolder.status
create one ArrayList of Integers and add values in it according to your condition listOfStatuses.add(0) or listOfStatuses.add(1).
Then pass this value to next ACtivity throught intent.
Then while creating Adapter pass this arrayList to CustomAdapter and use this List in Adapter as suggested in code above.

Comment: Some code hints plzz.. I am totally lost. From where should I start

Comment: Check this answer bShah and try to understand how I preserve state of checkbox.
Once you get it,try same logic for your imageviews in listview.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444165/android-how-to-identify-item-in-listview-with-checkbox/9445227#9445227